# How to use SQL Funtions like WEEK() in Typo3 (Extbase Repository) - Doctrine-DBAL?

Tags: database, doctrine, typo3, extbase, dbal

I want to use the WEEK() function on a datetime field to filter fo a specific week.

Im using

- TYPO3 v11.5
- Extbase

Inside my Repository I have

```
$queryBuilder = $this->connectionPool->getQueryBuilderForTable($this->getTableName()); 
$queryBuilder ->select('*'); 

$queryBuilder->where(
    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('week', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($pWeek));
);
```

I tried using `->addSelect('WEEK(myDateTime) AS week')` but this results in `'WEEK(start)' AS week`. (Where ' stands for ` )

Giving an SQL Syntax Error because there is no field 'WEEK(myDateTime)'

I know I can use the expression builder for some Aggregate functions.
Also I could get the Date form my $pWeek with php and just compare the two Dates.

But there must be an easy way to use such SQL functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `->addSelectLiteral()` for this.

Comment: Is this documented outside - https://api.typo3.org/TYPO3_8-7/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_database_1_1_query_1_1_query_builder.html#a31dadbf2e43d4f3f67a70de6f8f6bd62 ?

Comment: Kind of: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/ExpressionBuilder/Index.html